# incomplete installation of GCC on macos, still not recognized

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, homebrew

I need to install a library which needs `gcc` only.

I installed `gcc` on `macos` but it still is not getting recognized:

```
brew install gcc

Ignoring commonmarker-0.17.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine commonmarker --version 0.17.9
Ignoring commonmarker-0.17.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine commonmarker --version 0.17.9
Warning: gcc 8.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 8.2.0, run `brew reinstall gcc`
$ gcc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

How do I make it work? Reinstalling does not help. I added these lines to source:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile

alias gcc='gcc-8.2'
alias cc='gcc-8.2'
alias g++='g++-8.2'
alias c++='c++-8.2'
```

But still the error: `-bash: gcc-8.2: command not found`

Comment: Well, if you install GCC version 8.2.0 then you would have a hard time running GCC version 4.8. So those aliases are incorrect.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -bash: gcc-8.2: command not found .. versions probably got muddled somehow . plz see the edit :)

Comment: Please try `brew reinstall gcc` and watch all Brew messages carefully. It will output further instructions how to tune gcc for running gcc-8.2.0 from the command line.

Comment: @S.M. not helping: $ brew reinstall gcc
==> Reinstalling gcc 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-8.2.0.mojave.bottle.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/rafael/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5e336edb977168e21c1c3d0e1d374b76c39a8780ccee6b1e2d81a832a3f01118--gcc-8.2.0.mojave.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Pouring gcc-8.2.0.mojave.bottle.2.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0: 1,413 files, 295.9MB

Comment: Use `brew info gcc` to check what versions are installed but not currently activated.

Comment: @S.M. brew info gcc
gcc: stable 8.2.0 (bottled), HEAD
GNU compiler collection
https://gcc.gnu.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0 (1,413 files, 295.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-01-21 at 01:02:14
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gcc.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gmp ✔, isl ✔, libmpc ✔, mpfr ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
 Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 54,946 (30 days), 200,444 (90 days), 744,276 (365 days)
install_on_request: 27,214 (30 days), 99,657 (90 days), 351,621 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)

Comment: @S.M. how to activate gcc?

Comment: You must run `gcc-8` instead of `gcc`

Comment: I get the error, seems like compiler isnt getting recognized yet at all places: CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  /usr/local/bin/gcc.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

Comment: `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc-8` or `export CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc-8`

Comment: @S.M. don't know why but after the above command i get -bash: gcc-8: command not found..again the earlier error

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your PATHs? From that last error it sounds like you haven't set GCC anywhere in your PATH. Just out of curiosity, is this your first time downloading with homebrew?

Comment: @GKE yes, I mostly worked with ubuntu.

Comment: @GKE adding path to bash_profile export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" still doesnt recognize gcc

Comment: @Rafael Try edit `/etc/paths` by appending  /usr/local/bin on it's own line.